# What does it mean if react uses one event handler at the root of my document to listen and call the appropriate event handler?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

React has a great way for dealing with event handlers and event listeners with browser compatibility and improved performance but I am a bit confused of this part in this book, Learning React by Kirupa Chinnathambi, it says that:

> React never attaches event handlers to the DOM elements directly. It uses one event handler at the root of your document that is responsible for listening to all events and calling the appropriate event handler as necessary.

I am not 100% sure that I know what this means. However I do know that react uses components to wrap around the DOMs. But I don't understands what this does for event handlers. Someone please elaborate and give examples.

Comment: Have a look at [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Comment: I have read the article but I still don't get it. In that article it talked about how you can put an event listener in a parent element and if one of its children prompts the event it does the appropriate event handle. Does it mean that components just acts as parents within the event delegation?

Comment: __"it talked about how you can put an event listener in a parent element"__, yes that is what this line is saying is happening __"It uses one event handler at the root of your document"__ Meaning putting say a click event listener on say `document` will be triggered by a click event on any child element (unless stopPropagation is called in a child event listener). This is how DOM events work in browsers, has nothing really to do with React, React just utilizes it.

Comment: Ok I understand now! Thanks!